# find how many elements from the beginning of the array must be added to get a total of more than 10

Tags: javascript

I have an array with numbers. Need to find how many elements from the beginning of the array must be added to get a total of more than 10. In the code I have to use `reduce`

let arr = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4];

The console in this case must display the number 6.

My code didn't work:

```
let arr = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4];
let sumNumber = arr.reduce((sum, elem, index) => {

    let ourSum = 0;
    while (ourSum <= 10) {
        return sum + elem;
    }
    index++


}, 0)
console.log(sumNumber);
```

Comment: May you go through this line-by-line? I think it might help if you explain why you think it should work.

Comment: Have you read the mdn docs for reduce? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce that would also help.

Comment: I don't know who gave you the stupid task to do this with reduce. Like your previous question, this can easily be done with a regular for loop / other array methods.

Comment: You can use a while loop.

    let sum=0, i=0; 
    while(sum<=10 && i<arr.length) sum+=arr[i++];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4];
// i is to store the element count at which it gets greater than 10
let i=0;
let sumNumber = arr.reduce((sum, elem, index) => {
    // Checks if sum is greater than 10 yet?
    if(sum>=10){
        // this condn below will only evaluate once when for the
        // first time the sum is greater than or equal to 10
        if(i===0) i=index+1;
    }
    // updates the sum for every loop run
    return sum+elem;
});
console.log("Element count for which sum is greater than equal to 10 is:",i);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index and add one.

This iteration stops if the comparison is true.

```js
let array = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4],
    index = array.find((sum => value => (sum += value) > 10)(0));

console.log(index + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
const arr = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4]

const sumNumber = arr.reduce(
  (acc, cur, index) => {
    if (typeof acc === 'number') { // If the accumulator is a number...
      return acc // Just return it
    }
    const sum = acc.sum + cur
    if (sum > 10) { // If sum is greater than 10...
      return index + 1 // ...return a number
    }
    return { sum } // Return an object with sum with the new value
  },
  { sum: 0 } // Start with an object with the `sum` property of 0
)

console.log(sumNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `some` method, you do not have to loop through the rest of the elements when condition is achived.

```js
var arr = [2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4];
var obj = {sum : 0, index : 0 };

arr.some((k,i)=>{
 obj.sum+=k;
 if(obj.sum > 10) {
   obj.index = i+1;
   return true
  }
 });
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!